# Help needed with this linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

These two statements are equivalent.

a) x(a + b) = 8 + 5a

b) xa + xb = 8 + 5a

So why is that if we solve X for both of them... They both have different answers. For example a) will equal to x = 8 + 5a / a + b

But b) will equal to x + x = 8 + 5a / a + b, because essentially in b), we will divide the left side by 'a' and 'b', but that still leaves us with two X's. Please help to understand.

Comment: Your manipulation of $(b)$ is not correct.

Comment: Your manipulations in a) and b) are wrong in two differenti ways!

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, if you divide everything by $a$, what you get is$$x+\frac bax=\frac8a+5,$$and if you divide it by $b$, what you get is$$\frac abx+x=\frac8b+5.$$But, if you divide both sides by $a+b$, what you get is$$\frac{xa+xb}{a+b}=\frac{8+5a}{a+b}\quad\text{or}\quad x=\frac{8+5a}{a+b},$$just like in a). What you *cannot* do is to divide the $xa$ of $xa+xb$ by $a$ and the $xb$ by $b$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your working for part (b) is not correct. If $xa+xb=8+5a$, then
$$
\frac{xa+xb}{a+b}=\frac{8+5a}{a+b}
$$
but the left-hand side of this equation does not equal $x+x$. This is because
$$
(x+x)\times(a+b)\neq xa+xb \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @lambosvt: No problem! I’m glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.